# php add commas after each word if necessary

Tags: php

All I need is to add commas after each type:

For example:

if (a = 1) display **Coca Cola**

if (a = 1 and b = 1) display **Coca Cola, Fanta**

```
<?php 
echo 'Type:';
if ($a == 1) {echo 'Coca Cola';}
if ($b == 1) {echo 'Fanta';}  
if ($c == 1) {echo 'Sprite';} 
?>
```

Comment: yes, sorry for that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

It is always safe to use arrays and implode() because, even if you do not have any

element in it, it will not produce an error.

Also, with concatenation of , in the string, its complex to avoid , in the end and

complex logic e.g. setting counter etc.. is involved.

implode() gives you beauty and simplicity.

```
<?php 
echo 'Type:';
$types = array();    
if ($a == 1) {$types[] = 'Coca Cola';}
if ($b == 1) {$types[] = 'Fanta / All types';}  
if ($c == 1) {$types[] = 'Sprite';} 
echo implode(', ', $types);
?>
```

Comment: @EducateYourself, then please mark my answer as solution.

Comment: still have to wait 3 min to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php   

    echo 'Type: ';
    if ($a == 1) {echo 'Coca Cola';}
    if ($b == 1) {echo ($a == 1 ? ", ": "") . 'Fanta / All types';}  
    if ($c == 1) {echo ($b == 1 || $a == 1 ? ", ": "") . 'Sprite';} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean commas, you should add each value to an array and print them at the end with an appended comma after each item, trimming the final item to remove the comma from the end.

```
<?php
    $types = [];
    echo 'Type:';
    if ($a == 1) {$types[] = 'Coca Cola';}
    if ($b == 1) {$types[] = 'Fanta / All types';}  
    if ($c == 1) {$types[] = 'Sprite';} 

    echo rtrim(implode(', ', $types), ', ');
?>
```